# SQL FOR XML Path issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml

I have this query like so:

```
SELECT JOB_NUMBER AS 'Key' FROM table FOR XML PATH(''), Type
```

Which returns:

```
<Key>ORC0023</Key><Key>ORC0045</Key>
```

What I am trying to do is return it like so:

```
<ORC0023></ORC0023><ORC0045></ORC0045>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? There is no direct way to modify a columns name. That means, that you have no direct way to set an elements name dynamically. You might use dynamic SQL and build a statement and call it with `EXEC`, but please - as I think there's something wrong in design - explain what you really want...

Answer (score 0):

Since your output will have special characters `< >` you will need to return the result as xml by specifing `type` and use `xquery` to extract it as a string

```
declare @t table (job_number varchar(10))
insert into @t
select 'ORC0023' union all
select 'ORC0024' 

select
(
    select '<' + job_number + '></' + job_number + '>' 
    from @t
    for xml path(''), type
).value('/', 'varchar(max)')
```